# replicable apt-get install command

Tags: command-line, apt

I'm provisioning an Ubuntu server with a shell script, for definition a provisioning script should be replicable and idempotent (every time I execute the command it should always act the same). Thus I need to clearly define a package's version. In my case, I want to install *cURL 7.22.0*, so I've tried:

```
apt-get install curl=7.22.0
```

but this doesn't work since the version doesn't exist. So i've checked for specific version in my package's cache with `apt-cache madison curl`:

```
curl | 7.22.0-3ubuntu4.14 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
curl | 7.22.0-3ubuntu4.14 | http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
curl | 7.22.0-3ubuntu4 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
curl | 7.22.0-3ubuntu4 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main Sources
curl | 7.22.0-3ubuntu4.14 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main Sources
curl | 7.22.0-3ubuntu4.14 | http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main Sources
```

and I've thought that:

```
apt-get install curl=7.22.0-3ubuntu4.14
```

was a smart solution, but alas, after `apt-get update` that package disappered  and `7.22.0-3ubuntu4.15` come to life, and so the provisioning script doesn't work anymore.

As you can imagine this script is too fragile and completly unusefull. 
How can I avoid this nasty surprise?

Comment: You have to hold the package, but I would not suggest you to do that. This, because other packages/versions that get updated might need to install the new version of the library, and this will generate errors.

Comment: How about [pinning](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-apt-get.en.html#s-pin)?

Comment: If I destroy the provisioned machine and I want to recreate a new machine with the same package in the same version pinning can't help me